# Passing fragment's B saved state to Activity A

Tags: java, android

My question is somewhat theoretical (I apologize for the lack of code, but I'm not even sure if this is possible).

I have two activities and two fragments (each fragment corresponding to one activity). Activity A (in portrait mode) only displays fragment A. Activity B (in portrait mode) only displays fragment B.

My problem appears when Activity A (MainActivity) in landscape has to display fragment A (that belongs to itself) and fragment B (that belongs to activity B). I can not seem to be able to save on to activity A (MainActivity) the state of fragment B.

This is what I've tried in fragment B:

```
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRetainInstanceState();
}
...
```

Can I use this code to save the state of fragment B (all its local variables)?

In activity A (MainActivity) I tried to detect if the device is on landscape:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // restore fragment's B state so the recent data passed into it shows up 
    // in landscape (in Activity A).    
}

else {
    // keep doing what you're doing in portrait view.   
}
```

Every time I rotate my device, fragment B comes back empty, even though in portrait mode I have data displaying (data passed from selecting an item from a list in fragment A).

How do I capture the state of fragment B in this particular case? Thanks much.

Comment: To clarify, when you are in landscape mode, you are showing both Fragment-A and Fragment-B, but the host is Activity-A. Correct?  And you want to initialize Fragment-B with the same state that was likely preserved via onSaveState when it was previously hosted by Activity-B. Correct?

Comment: @selbie yes, basically I'd like that once I passed the data from activity A to activity B to the frabment B, to retrieve that fragment back to the mainActivity (activity A) in landscape showing frabment B with the variables that were last passed. I'm sorry this sounds so ... convoluted :) Yes, host is activity A

Answer (score 0):

You could save the state that isn't particular to a view in a bundle, and on every resume of a fragment's life cycle ( when redisplayed for example), you should also be reloading that bundle.  This requires you to know the specific things that other activities/fragments will be interested in retrieving from your fragment, but its better to fail from the fragment responsible for providing that info than fail on the receiving end for unknown reasons (IMO)

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please give me a simple example about how the saving would happen, and how/where the targeting of that bundle would occur